# How to group js array messages in 1 minute increments

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to draw a list of messages in a chat room.
The messages are printed in array obejct in the order in which they were sent.

The array has an object containing the time and text of the message sent.

Array example

```
[
   {
      "text": "This is group message",
      "createdAt":1589213916843, // May 12, 2020, 01:18 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Kevin'
      },
   },
   {
      "text": "This is group message",
      "createdAt":1589213923852, // May 12, 2020, 01:18 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Kevin'
      },
   },
   {
      "text": "This is not group message",
      "createdAt":1589213974514, // May 12, 2020, 01:19 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Bob'
      },
   }
]
```

I want to change this array like this!

The result I want

```
[
   {
      "createdAt": 1589213916843, // May 12, 2020, 01:18 AM,
      "user":{
          "name": 'Kevin'
      },
      "messages": [
         {
            "text": "This is group message",
         },
         {
            "text": "This is group message",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "createdAt":1589213923852, // May 12, 2020, 01:19 AM
      "user": {
         name: 'Bob'
      },
      "messages": [
         {
            "text": "This is group message",
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I want to group the message sender and the send time in 1 minute increments.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will group messages in 1 minute intervals. The comments explain how it works.

```js
const messages = [
   {
      "text": "This is group message",
      "createdAt":1589213916843, // May 12, 2020, 01:18 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Kevin'
      },
   },
   {
      "text": "This is group message",
      "createdAt":1589213923852, // May 12, 2020, 01:18 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Kevin'
      },
   },
   {
      "text": "This is not group message",
      "createdAt":1589213974514, // May 12, 2020, 01:19 AM
      "user":{
         "name": 'Bob'
      },
   }
];

const unique = [];
// Loop through messages
messages.forEach((message) => {

   // Get integer timestamp with seconds and milliseconds set to 0 (to group by minutes)
   let time = new Date(message.createdAt);
   time.setSeconds(0);
   time.setMilliseconds(0);
   let createdAtMinutes = time.getTime();

   // Try to get existing message group
   let currentGroup = unique.filter(msgGrp => msgGrp.createdAt === createdAtMinutes);

   // If we've got the existing group, add the message, otherwise create a new group
   if(currentGroup.length) {
       currentGroup[0].messages.push(message);
   } else {
       unique.push({ "createdAt": createdAtMinutes, "messages": [message] });
   }
});

console.log(unique);
```